# java.io.EOFException: \n not found: size=0 content=…

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp, eofexception

I am getting following exception in API request. I have tried solutions mentioned in this website and on OkHttp Github page but still this issue is not fixed.

```
HTTP FAILED: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on https://example.com
W/System.err: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on https://example.com
...
at com.skycap.rodeobuddy.apis.HeaderInterceptor.intercept(HeaderInterceptor.kt:11)
...
at com.skycap.rodeobuddy.apis.ConnectivityInterceptor.intercept(ConnectivityInterceptor.kt:19)
...
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: limit=0 content=…
at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.kt:231)
```

Code:

```
  fun okHttpClient(context: Context): OkHttpClient {
        val cookieManager = CookieManager()
        cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL)

        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .cookieJar(JavaNetCookieJar(cookieManager))
            .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .writeTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .addNetworkInterceptor(getHttpLoggingInterceptor())
            .addInterceptor(ConnectivityInterceptor(context))
            .addInterceptor(HeaderInterceptor())
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            .hostnameVerifier(HostName())
            .build()
    }

private fun getHttpLoggingInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor {
        val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        httpLoggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        return httpLoggingInterceptor
    }
```

HeaderInterceptor:

```
class HeaderInterceptor : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain) : Response {               
        val request = chain.request().newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Connection", "close")
            .build()
        return chain.proceed(request)
    }
}
```

ConnectivityInterceptor:

```
class ConnectivityInterceptor(private val mContext: Context) : Interceptor {

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        if (!mContext.isNetworkAvailable()) {
            throw UnknownHostException()
        }

        val builder = chain.request().newBuilder()
        return chain.proceed(builder.build())
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you need more details.